# Form not editable if no match is found using UI-Bootstrap's typeahead directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Below is the relevant code for how my typeahead input box is setup. Essentially, the user types in a name and the relevant information is loaded into the rest of the form. In the case that no match is found, I'd like the user to still be able to enter the name and relevant information into the form.

When no matches are found, the form is not editable. As an example, if I type "John Doe" into the name, and there are no matches, I cannot type into the "address" input box, the code of which is shown below.

**Typeahead:**

```
<label for="participant-name">Name</label>
<input name="participant-name" typeahead="participant as participant.name for participant in participants | filter:$viewValue | limitTo: 8" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="entry.participant">
```

**Sample input box:**

```
<label for="participant-street-no">Address</label>
<input name="participant-street-no" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="entry.participant.street">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you type a string into the typeahead, entry.participant is now that string, and not an object. You can't add .street to a string. Instead you need to create an new object, take the entry.participant string and assign it to that object as .name, and then set entry.participant to the object.

Here's how I would do it: First set typeahead editable to false. Add a button to the typeahead input box (bootstrap's input groups do a good job of this) that says "New" and hides the typeahead and replaces it with another input box with a model of entry.participant.name. As soon as they click new, set entry.participant = {}. You could also swap that "New" out for a "Cancel" or an "X" at this point.

### Edit

Here's a [plunker!](http://plnkr.co/edit/jrh1XXK2scSxxvxtmeRy?p=preview)
I kept the typeahead editable so you can see the difference in the model when you select Bob or Jim compared to when you just type a string. Otherwise the model won't be set until you select something from the dropdown.